# How to join the most recent time prior to the current row time (Pyspark 2.4.4 Dataframes)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do the following:

I have 2 dataframes in Pyspark "df1" looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | SMS Created |Content|
+----+-------------+-------+
| 1  | 12:00:00    | a     |
+----+-------------+-------+
| 2  | 13:00:00    | b     |
+----+-------------+-------+
| 3  | 11:00:00    | c     |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

df2 looks like this:

```
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Event   | Time     | id | Members |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Created | 11:30:00 | 1  | [1,2]   |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Updated | 11:42:00 | 1  | [1,2,3] |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Updated | 11:50:00 | 1  | [1,2,4] |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Updated | 12:50:00 | 1  | [1,2]   |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Created | 12:30:00 | 2  | [1,2]   |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Updated | 12:42:00 | 2  | [1,2,3] |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Updated | 12:50:00 | 2  | [1,2,4] |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Updated | 13:10:00 | 2  | [1,2]   |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Created | 10:30:00 | 3  | [1,2]   |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Updated | 10:42:00 | 3  | [1,2,3] |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Updated | 10:50:00 | 3  | [1,2,4] |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
| Updated | 12:10:00 | 2  | [1,2]   |
+---------+----------+----+---------+
```

df2 is Updated every time the members change but the messages are only sent to whoever is a "Member" prior to the "SMS Created" time.

Note that there are Updated times AFTER the "SMS Created" time so using any kind of MAX()function without conditions doesn't work here. I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this.

How would you join the most recent "Event" PRIOR to the "SMS Created" so the table looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| id | SMS Created | Content | Event   | Time     | Members |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| 1  | 12:00:00    | a       | Updated | 11:50:00 | [1,2.4] |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| 2  | 13:00:00    | b       | Updated | 12:50:00 | [1,2,4] |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| 3  | 11:00:00    | c       | Updated | 10:50:00 | [1,2,4] |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
```

I'm using Pyspark 2.4.4 with the Dataframe API. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`welcome to SO`

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("id")
df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("id","id2"), (F.col("id")==F.col("id2"))&(F.col("SMS Created")>F.col("Time"))).drop("id2")\
   .withColumn("max", F.max("Time").over(w))\
   .filter('max=Time').drop("max").orderBy("id").show()

#+---+-----------+-------+-------+--------+---------+
#| id|SMS Created|Content|  Event|    Time|  Members|
#+---+-----------+-------+-------+--------+---------+
#|  1|   12:00:00|      a|Updated|11:50:00|[1, 2, 4]|
#|  2|   13:00:00|      b|Updated|12:50:00|[1, 2, 4]|
#|  3|   11:00:00|      c|Updated|10:50:00|[1, 2, 4]|
#+---+-----------+-------+-------+--------+---------+
```